# List row task / onAppear not called

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm encountering a strange behaviour with `List` when using section and either `task` or `onAppear`.

Let's say I have a list with sections and rows in each section. When I put a `task` to run a async task when each row appears, it doesn't call it even though it's displayed on screen. The same problem applies when using `onAppear` instead of `task`.

It's easily reproducible with the given example. You can just run and scroll down to the bottom. You'll notice that the last task isn't called despite the row and the section is on screen.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  private var dataSource: [Int: [String]] = (0..<30).reduce([Int: [String]]()) { result, key in
    var result = result
    let items = (0..<4).map { "Item \($0)" }

    result[key] = items

    return result
  }


  var body: some View {
    List {
      ForEach(Array(dataSource.keys), id: \.self) { section in
        let rows = dataSource[section]

        Section {
          ForEach(rows ?? [], id: \.self) { row in
            Text("\(row)")
          }
          .task {
            print("TASK \(section)")
          }
        } header: {
          Text("Section \(section)")
        }

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone has an explanation ? Am I missing something ?

I managed to fix this problem by using a `ScrollView` which embeds a `LazyVStack`, but by doing so I'm loosing some of the features from `List`, such as swipe to delete.

Comment: Try putting the task on the Tect instead of on the loop

Comment: @loremipsum I've already tried it. It's the same behaviour.

Comment: The interesting thing is that is seems to work fine when they're no sections.... Could it just be a bug in SwiftUI?

Comment: @Nonouf is this issue resolved?

Comment: @Lenin not really, we went for another solution.

Answer (score 1):

`.task` is when the underlying `UIView` appears, which in the case of `List` is a `UICollectionViewCell` and those only appear once and are reused when scrolling so have already appeared so `.task` won't run again.

Btw `ForEach` is not a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I was found this solution on this way. May be help for you.

```
    private var dataSource: [Int: [String]] = (0..<30).reduce([Int: [String]]()) { result, key in
        var result = result
        let items = (0..<4).map { "Item \($0)" }
        result[key] = items
        return result
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        let arrData = dataSource.keys.sorted()
        List {
            ForEach(Array(arrData), id: \.self) { section in
                let rows = dataSource[section]
                
                Section {
                    ForEach(rows ?? [], id: \.self) { row in
                        Text("\(row)")
                    }
                    .task {
                        print("TASK \(section)")
                    }
                } header: {
                    Text("Section \(section)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything. In my example `task` and on `onAppear` works the same way.